# Why am I getting this 404 error suddenly?

Tags: wordpress, security

My site worked fine just a few hours ago. And I have not touched it since then. However, as of now, every single page except for the homepage is showing the following message:

> 404 Not Found
>
> The resource requested could not be found on this server! Powered By
>   LiteSpeed Web Server LiteSpeed Technologies is not responsible for
>   administration and contents of this web site!

The homepage seems to work fine. I can't see any changes and I also scanned it with http://sitecheck3.sucuri.net/ and it returned nothing. I do however, have a plugin called Better WP Security installed and it says that there have been some "Bad login attempts" just before that and that all my WP core files has been modified.

I am not sure what to do now as I don't know how to confirm whether I have been hacked or not.

Could it be my host's fault? Found a thread in a forum with a similar issue:
http://www.ukbusinessforums.co.uk/threads/404-not-found-the-resource-requested-could-not-be-found-on-this-server.291094/

Comment: Did you log into your FTP and see if the files were still there?

Comment: Yes the Wordpress files are still there. I assume that's why my Homepage is still intact.

Comment: Surely you have a backup, just restore it.

Comment: This is likely the result of something completely innocent. Do the following. Delete your .htaccess. Go to wp-admin/ -> Settings -> Permalinks and hit save to regenerate the file. Test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like your `.htaccess` file has been nuked somehow. A plugin attempting to edit it might have corrupted it (I've seen it before). In any case, download a fresh copy of WordPress and re-upload the `.htaccess` file into the home directory. Alternatively, you can change your permalinks settings to have it generated automatically.

If your site got hacked, typically you will see some hidden `div`s and malicious `script` tags injected into your page and/or within your database. If this happens, you need to restore your most recent backup of your files and database. The files on the server should all be considered compromised and a known clean copy must be used.

Comment: Thanks SamT and Nathan, resetting the htaccess solved it. I'm glad that it's not due to my site being compromised. I wonder what caused it though, so I could avoid that from happening in the future.

Comment: Hi Sam, Can you please help me how to reset .htaccess file as I am facing  exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 6):

I solved this problem by another simple way...
On a Dashboard - go to Settings, then Permalinks and click Save Changes.
It works perfectly for me.

Comment: this works for me. i saved it and everything become OK

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and saving the permalinks configuration solved for me. As stated here, it happens because there is no .htacess file or that file is corrupted, but I would like to add an observation, at least in my case I didn't have a htacess file because I took a backup from another server and forgot to enable the option to show hidden dot files, thus ending up not including the htacess file in the backup package.

Answer (score -1):

Check the permission given to `.htaccess` file it must be 755 `7=rwx 5=r-x 5=r-x`

```
Permission    Action      chmod option
======================================
read          (view)      r or 4
write         (edit)      w or 2
execute       (execute)   x or 1
```